# colors that apple supports for rounded buttons

Tags: iphone

can anyone suggest the background colors that apple support for rounded buttons..Is there any guidelines for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any background color that you like, even pattern colors (`[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:...]`) do work fine.

Answer (score 0):

There are no restrictions for background Colors as far as I know. You can use any color for your button's background.